# Animation lost when clicking on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` which contains a list of item that implement a boolean property called `ResultChanged`, this property allow me to create a blink effect on a particular cell of the `DataGrid`, in particular, if the property is setted to `true` then the cell of the `DataGrid` will colored by orange and blinking for 5 seconds, at the end of the animation, the color will keeped on the `DataGrid` and this working well for me, except for one problem.

*Problem*

When I click on the `DataGrid` (any rows) the color applied by the animation will be removed, but I want that such color remain on the cell.

This is my code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource hour}" Binding="{Binding Result}">
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True" >
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="Blink" 
                                    AutoReverse="True" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="5x">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                     Value="Orange" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                     Value="Black" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard AutoReverse="False">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="Orange" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

someone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation's effects will be lost when you select or unselect the row affected by the animation, because `DataGrid` changes the foreground and background brushes of the selected row. Now, normally, the animation's changes to the `Foreground` and `Background` properties would have [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) over those changes for the selected row.
But your animation does not animate `Foreground` and `Background`! Instead, it animates `Foreground.Color` and `Background.Color`; these changes have no precedence and will be lost when something else changes `Foreground` or `Background` directly.

Therefore, your animation must animate `Foreground` and `Background` directly. Then, the changes will remain in effect even after the animation has ended.

You could achieve this, for example, by using the `BrushAnimation` class from the answer in question [Brush to Brush Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096852/brush-to-brush-animation) and using a storyboard similar to this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True" >
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="Blink" 
                            RepeatBehavior="5x">
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="White" To="Orange" />
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="Yellow" To="Black" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution that allows `AutoReverse` to be set to true:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True" >
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <!-- The next two animations will take 10 seconds: -->
                <Storyboard x:Name="Blink" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="5x">
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:1" From="White" To="Orange"/>
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:1" From="Yellow" To="Black"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <!-- Same animations as above, but BeginTime offset by 10 seconds and neither repeat nor auto reverse: -->
                <Storyboard x:Name="finalBlink" BeginTime="00:00:10">
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:1" From="White" To="Orange"/>
                    <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" 
                                            BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:1" From="Yellow" To="Black"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: `local` is the namespace in which you have added the code for `BrushAnimation`. E.g. if the C# namespace is called `WpfApplication12`, then you would have to add the declaration `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12"` at the top of your XAML. Of course, you can use another name than `local`.

Comment: is possible slow down the speed of the animation? how?

Comment: @Charanoglu Set a larger value to the `Duration` properties, e.g. `Duration="0:0:2"` would be two seconds.

Comment: is possible set a fade in effect? I tried auto reverse and this works but I got again the bug of the question...