# Continuous background brush animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, brush

I want to make a continuous brush animation whenever the mouse is over my usercontrol.

I already have this:

```
    private void MainControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        BeginColorAnimation(Background, BackgroundHover);
    }

    private void BeginColorAnimation(Brush from, Brush to)
    {            
        BrushAnimation anim = new BrushAnimation()
        {
            From = from,
            To = to,
            Duration = AnimationDuration
        };
        
        BackgroundBorder.BeginAnimation(Border.BackgroundProperty, anim);                        
    }        

    private void MainControl_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        BeginColorAnimation(BackgroundHover, Background);
    }
```

The BrushAnimation class can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096852/brush-to-brush-animation)

The problem i have right now is that if i move the mouse quickly over the control, the Background of my control shifts from the Background brush to the BackgroundHover brush (or viceversa) instantly and i don't want that.

How can i make this to look like a continuous change between brushes?

**EDIT 1**

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DU_bDucXzA) you can see a video of the problem i have.

Let me explain myself:

Imagine we have two brushes, one black and one blue (or any other color). When the mouse is over the control i want to change the background of my color from black to blue, and when the mouse exits the control i want to change the background back to black.
So what happens if the mouse is over the control and exits halfway the animation? It looks like if was bouncing from one brush to another. I want to avoid that.

I tried using:

```
private void MainControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    BeginColorAnimation(BackgroundBorder.Background, BackgroundHover);
}

private void MainControl_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    BeginColorAnimation(BackgroundBorder.Background, Background);
}
```

But then i receive: 'System.InvalidOperationException' This freezable cannot be frozen.

**EDIT 2**

Ended up using a SolidColorBrush instead of a Brush, and using the ColorAnimation class.

```
public bool BackgroundFrozen = true;

        private void MainControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            BeginColorAnimation((SolidColorBrush)BackgroundBorder.Background, BackgroundHover);
        }

        private void BeginColorAnimation(SolidColorBrush from, SolidColorBrush to)
        {
            if(BackgroundFrozen)
            {
                BackgroundBorder.Background = BackgroundBorder.Background.CloneCurrentValue();
                BackgroundFrozen = false;
            }

            ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation()
            {                
                From = from.Color,
                To = to.Color,
                Duration = AnimationDuration
            };
            
            BackgroundBorder.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, anim);
        }        

        private void MainControl_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            BeginColorAnimation((SolidColorBrush)BackgroundBorder.Background, Background);
        }
```

For some reason the Border Background property is frozen at first, so i used a BackgroundFrozen bool to "Unfreeze" it with CloneCurrentValue() when the animation runs for first time.

Result [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnCVCz34HvQ)

Comment: Is "MainControl" an instance of (or derived from) some existing WPF control?

If so it probably has a ControlTemplate with VisualStates, including a MouseOver state.  That's likely what's killing your animation.  You'll probably need to redefine the ControlTemplate to prevent this.   

You can copy the controlTemplate from the VisualDesigner, then edit it to remove the states..

Comment: <UserControl x:Name="MainControl"><borders and labels and stuff/><UserControl/> I named it MainControl to bind some custom properties but thats not the problem. 

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DU_bDucXzA) is a video of the problem i have. As you can see the animation plays well but when i move the mouse quickly over the control, the background of my control shifts from one brush to another instantly, maybe the word "continuous" isn't the correct word so, How can i make it look smooth and not like if it was bouncing from one color to another?

Comment: Remove `From = from,`. Then the animation will start from the current value.
But perhaps for improvement you will have to set the `Duration` value not by the `AnimationDuration` constant, but to decrease it proportionally to the `from` value.

Comment: @EldHasp You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

READ "EDIT 2" AS IT IS PART OF THE SOLUTION

As suggested by someone, i removed `From = from,` and make a "dynamic" duration for the animation taking into account the `from` and the `end` values.

Result:

`start` is the original value 
`end` is the target value 
`actual` is something between `start` and `end` (could be the same)

```
private ColorAnimation GetColorAnimation(SolidColorBrush start, SolidColorBrush end, SolidColorBrush actual)
        {
            ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation()
            {                
                To = end.Color,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetAnimationDuration(start, end, actual)))
            };

            return anim;
        }
```

`GetAnimationDuration` returns a `double` that contains the duration in milliseconds

```
private double GetAnimationDuration(SolidColorBrush start, SolidColorBrush end, SolidColorBrush actual)
        {
            Color s = start.Color;
            Color e = end.Color;
            Color a = actual.Color;

            double Rdif = Math.Abs(s.R - e.R);
            double Gdif = Math.Abs(s.G - e.G);
            double Bdif = Math.Abs(s.B - e.B);            

            //Console.WriteLine("Rdif: {0}, Gdif: {1}, Bdif: {2}", Rdif, Gdif, Bdif);

            double Rp = Math.Abs(a.R - e.R) / Rdif;
            double Gp = Math.Abs(a.G - e.G) / Gdif;
            double Bp = Math.Abs(a.B - e.B) / Bdif;

            double p = 0;
            int c = 0;

            if(!double.IsNaN(Rp))
            {
                p += Rp;
                c += 1;
            }

            if (!double.IsNaN(Gp))
            {
                p += Gp;
                c += 1;
            }

            if (!double.IsNaN(Bp))
            {
                p += Bp;
                c += 1;
            }

            p /= c;

            //Console.WriteLine("Rp: {0}, Gp: {1}, Bp: {2}", Rp, Gp, Bp);

            double r = p * AnimationDuration;

            //Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", r);

            return r;
        }
```

And it's called like this:

```
BackgroundBorder.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, GetColorAnimation(startColor, endColor, (SolidColorBrush)BackgroundBorder.Background));
```

Test results from `GetAnimationDuration()` with a duration of 500 ms

```
---------------------------
Mouse enter
---------------------------
R: 0, G: 0, B: 255
Rdif: 255, Gdif: 0, Bdif: 255
Rp: 1, Gp: NaN, Bp: 1
Result: 500
---------------------------
Mouse leave (after having passed half of the animation (approximately))
---------------------------
R: 193, G: 0, B: 182
Rdif: 255, Gdif: 0, Bdif: 255
Rp: 0,756862745098039, Gp: NaN, Bp: 0,286274509803922
Result: 260,78431372549
```